# How can I display the registered soccer teams in a chart using Python

Tags: django, algorithm, graph, openpyxl

Below is my code and Excel file I generated. Now I need to display the teams in figure as a knockout tournament.

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Team, TieSheet
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.styles import Font
from openpyxl import Workbook
from django.http import HttpResponse
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.styles import Font, PatternFill, Alignment, borders
from django.http import HttpResponse
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from django.core.files import File
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

def tie_sheet(request):
    # Load the Excel template
    workbook = load_workbook(filename='static/excel/Tie-sheet.xlsx')
    
    # Get the active worksheet
    worksheet = workbook.active
    
    # Create merged cell for POLL1 and POLL2 columns and set heading
    worksheet.merge_cells(start_row=1, start_column=2, end_row=1, end_column=3)
    worksheet.cell(row=1, column=2, value='POLL1')
    worksheet.cell(row=1, column=4, value='POLL2')
    
    # Get the teams from the database
    teams = Team.objects.all().order_by('?')
    
    # Fill the data into the worksheet
    row_num = 2
    count = 1
    col = 2
    for team in teams:
        cell = worksheet.cell(row=row_num, column=col, value=team.title)
        cell.border = borders.Border(left=borders.Side(style='thin'), right=borders.Side(style='thin'), top=borders.Side(style='thin'), bottom=borders.Side(style='thin'))
        
        if col == 2:
            col = 4
            row_num = row_num
        elif col == 4:
            col = 2
            row_num += 2
        count = count+2
    
    # Add spacing between rows and columns
    for row in worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1):
        for cell in row:
            cell.font = Font(size=12, bold=True)
            cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
            #cell.fill = PatternFill(start_color='000000', end_color='000000', fill_type='solid')
    
    for col in worksheet.iter_cols(min_col=2, max_col=4):
        for cell in col:
            cell.font = Font(size=12, bold=True)
            cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
            #cell.fill = PatternFill(start_color='000000', end_color='000000', fill_type='solid')
    
    # Create a response with the filled Excel file
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=teams.xlsx'
    workbook.save(response)
    
    return response
```

I need to generate this type of graph with the registered teams mentioned previously.

Comment: Openpyxl can create Excel charts see [Openpyxl Charts](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/introduction.html). There is not much information like what charting, type and data in your post to help further.